# Do plasmons depend on the ambient EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

Imagine a situation:
There's an illuminated metal slab in vacuum. Normally, there are some plasmons created running all over the slab. What would happen if we had turned a giant magnet near the slab? Or put the slab between two electrically biased plates? How would plasmons react?